# Maven archetype quickstart with resources folder

Tags: maven

When I use **Maven archetype quickstart**, it does not create **src/main/resources**
folder and I have to create it myself. Why is it like this?

I want **src/main/resources** to be created automatically.

Is there a better **archetype** for this?

Comment: Somebody please answer this.... I know someone out there has the answer.

Comment: This is the way this archetype is done. It has no resource folder. Create a folder for one project or a new archetype if working on many projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are frequently creating projects from quickstart but require a resources directory, then [create your own custom archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) and install it to your repository (local cache or the one used by your team).

The source for the archetype, which you can check out anonymously and modify, is here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/archetypes/trunk/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Answer (score 4):

This maven archetype is an enhanced combination of the quickstart and webapp maven archetypes:

https://github.com/sabram/maven-archetype-quickweb

The project it creates will include both src/main/java and src/main/resources as well as src/test and src/webapp...

Feel free to use and delete any folders you don't need, or fork the archetype for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. The only solution that I've found was create the `/src/main/resources` and also `/src/main/java` for myself. Other parts of `maven-archetype` works fine for me.